# Checkbox based on array in React: controlled vs uncontrolled component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of values in the state, something like:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] // in this.state.values
```

This array of values are used to control the status of checkboxes. So, there are three checkboxes, and each have a `onChange` property like this:

```
<input
   type="checkbox"
   name={name}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```

The `handleChange` method just add or remove values from the array.

So naïvely, I thought I could just check the presence of the value in the array to know if the checkbox is checked or not. So I have done this:

```
<input
   type="checkbox"
   name={name}
   checked={this.state.values.find(e => e === name)}
   onChange={this.toggle}
/>
```

But this returns a warning:

> Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type checkbox to be uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

I'm not sure to understand, because I think the component is still controlled... The `checked` condition is based on state, so I thought it could work. How could I avoid this warning by still continue to use the array for reference?

Comment: is this happening when you uncheck the box or on initial rendering?

Comment: Can we see your whole component? I can't quite understand the structure. Are you creating dynamically those checkboxes? Most probably yes, then when your `handleChange` method removes a value from the array, are you rendering just the reminder checkboxes? If so then how do you add a value again to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of finding in array you should use `array.includes`. Your issue is related [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6779) bug in React which is removed in new version.

I have created a sandbox for you.

[image: Edit React and SCSS]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an initial value set for the state? If not, that could be the issue. If this.state is not yet set, then your input is initially uncontrolled. Set an initial state of your component like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { values: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] };
  }
```